# facebook share button showing wrong picture

Tags: php, facebook, image, share

```
{
"id": "242856279230384",
"url": "http://plankingaround.com/?id=585",
"type": "book",
"title": "planking Around Photos",
"image": [
  {
     "url": "http://plankingaround.com/pics/585.jpg",
     "width": 400,
     "height": 526
  }
 ],
 "site_name": "Planking Around Photos",
 "admins": [
  {
     "id": "1253531138",
     "name": "Chuck Bridges"
  }
  ],
   "updated_time": "2014-02-01T01:18:35+0000",
   "created_time": "2014-01-27T03:57:50+0000",
   "is_scraped": true
  }
```

This is my Facebook graph API but it is saying "Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'http://plankingaround.com/pics/defaultimage.jpg' will be used instead." Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the error you received is an old legacy message. 600 x 315 seems to be the new minimum requirement for an image based on this link:

[Best Practices: Image size](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/#images)

If the og:image specified does not meet their display requirements, FB will simply grab the image with the highest resolution on your page, which in your case was the default image.

In any case, FB is notoriously finicky when it comes to which og:images it will display. My best suggestion would be to try your image again with a different resolution. (1.91:1 aspect ratio is recommended.)